# IE 6 and the multiple button elements all sending their name & values

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

When using multiple button elements in a form, I realised that IE7 sends the innerHTML instead of the value of the button. All good I thought, I'll simply change my PHP code to this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['button-name'])) {
   add_product_to_cart(2);
}

?>
```

Now my old friend IE6 is going a little step further at being a nuisance. It sends all of the button elements regardless of which one I click. For example, I have 3 button elements named 'mint', 'near-mint' & 'standard'. A quick `print_r($_POST)` tells me that all 3 names have been submitted.

I guess to remedy this will be some JavaScript, not the most elegant situation, but I can imagine that the average user still using IE6 is not bright enough to turn off their JavaScript.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML of the form?

Comment: @Darryl: I could but it is unnecessary. It's a known issue. I was looking for a way to handle serverside with PHP (impossible) so I was wondering how I could manipulate it client side before it's sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution at http://www.codecomments.com/JavaScript/message756646.html

All credit to the author on that page.

Per request, here is the code

```
function buttonfix(){
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i].onclick = function () {
for(j=0; j<this.form.elements.length; j++)
if( this.form.elements[j].tagName == 'BUTTON' )
this.form.elements[j].disabled = true;
this.disabled=false;
}
}
}
window.attachEvent("onload", buttonfix);
```

Comment: You should post the code you used so people who Google this page will be able to find your solution.  (The page you linked to may not last forever.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Internet Explorer.

http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html describes a workaround that does not depend on JavaScript.

It boils down to "Use `<input>` and don't design your buttons to need anything other than simple text for their labels".

Answer (score 0):

An solution is to use `<input type="button">` and `<input type="submit">` in your page instead of `<button type="button">` and `<button>`.

**Update:** if you change your `button` elements to `input` elements you should be able to find them using jQuery with the following selector:

```
var buttons = $('input[type=submit], input[type=button]');
```

Comment: How does having 4 buttons prove to be a problem?

Comment: Because I need to know exactly which one was clicked.

Comment: So replace each button with an input?

The point I was trying to make is that the submission bug only affects button elements and does not affect input[type=submit] and input[type=button] elements.

You should be able to find these in jQuery using the selector:

    var buttons = $('input[type=submit], input[type=button]');

Comment: I used buttons because I needed to style them with images and text. Also, finding them with jQuery doesn't solve my problem. My problem is IE6 submits all values from all buttons regardless of which one is pressed. See the link in the accepted answer.