# Postback intermittently not working with ASP.NET 3.5 and IE?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, .net-3.5, iis-7, postback

We have an ASP.NET application that we recently migrated onto a new server with IIS7 and .NET 3.5.

In this new environment, some users that are on IE (6, 7, or 8) are experiencing bizarre intermittent problems with postback not working on ASP.NET buttons. (you click the button and nothing happens)

The issue happens sporadically. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. For some users the button postback almost never works (but sometimes yes!). To complicate matters there are some pages with asp.net button postbacks that DO always work.

Other pages contain a mix of 'asp buttons' and 'asp link buttons', in which the asp button postbacks often don't work, but the link button postbacks always work.

Javascript is enabled and works. The source DOES contain valid  tags.

I actually managed to take View Source snapshots of the same page when it was working and when it was not working and the source was EXACTLY the same!!!

At first I thought it was a problem with IE6, but it's now been reproduced on IE7 on one user's machine.

How would I even BEGIN to tackle this problem?

Any help, ideas, or guidance would be vastly appreciated. I am at the end of my mental rope here.

Comment: Tracking down a similar issue in .NET v4 and found this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is pretty old, but I found the same problem in my code.

I am using the ComponentArt component library.

In certain circumstances after a postback, buttons with codebehind will no longer execute in IE.  I also noticed that buttons with onClientSide clicks would execute their postback when the JS function completes and returns true.

I was able to get all the buttons on the page to submit by adding the following code to my buttons:

OnClientClick="javascript:return true"

Any buttons that are already running a JS function and returning true, should work without issue.

Answer (score 1):

See if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567958/ie-6-and-the-multiple-button-elements-all-sending-their-name-values/568038#568038) helps?  IE 6 treats buttons a little differently, especially if you have some name conflicts.  I could see this being a problem for events if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't ASP.NET always ensure that there are no naming conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit.

It was ComponentArt's 2007 Web.UI components that were being dropped on the page.

Apparently the menu control mixed with the 3.5 framework causes wierd issues with postback not working.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue when using Telerik controls in ASP.NET 3.5 web app. How did you sort this out? Thanks in advance... cheers

Comment: Sad to say, we disabled use of the control for the time being. My last thought before giving up was to try upgrading to a newer version of the telerik controls. Let us know if you manage to do it!